# How do I make this shape in pure HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Here's a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXBrEO) of what I currently have in my attempt to recreate this shape, and here's what I'm trying to make it look like the image below.
I'm not certain how to make the bottom of the box look rounded, and box-radius does not seem sufficient.

I've pasted my mark-up below for posterity.

```
<div id="DIV_1">
<a href="#close" id="A_2">×</a>
<div id="DIV_3">
    <div id="DIV_4">
        <b id="B_5">13</b> min
    </div>
</div>
<div id="DIV_6">
    <div id="DIV_7">
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: i can do for you.. but why no image ?

Comment: What do you mean by why no image?

Comment: I have embedded the image for you

Comment: Out of curiosity, why pure HTML/CSS and not SVG?

Comment: Because I'm manipulating/styling inserted HTML, CSS that is spat out by Mapbox @MaximillianLaumeister

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic idea:

2 main shapes, #one to create top-div, just set height and border-radius.
and #two has 3 divs to create the side's (.skippy's) and the bubble into the middle to create the bubble..

Set height of #two not more than 2/3 of skippy's and you will be fine.

this is a basic scrats.. don't use it.. use it to create your own :p

```css
#one {
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: pink;
}
#two {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
}
.bubble {
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  height: 150px;
}
.skippy1,
.skippy2 {
  background-color: white;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  height: 150px;
}
.skippy2 {
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 100px;
  border-top-left-radius: 100px;
}
.skippy1 {
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 100px;
  border-top-right-radius: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="two">
  <div class="skippy1 skippy">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="bubble">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="skippy2 skippy">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

EDIT (asker ask for more stuff, transparent etc..): 
you make a holder: set width place 2 divs,#one for top-div, #two to create the bubble...

```css
#holder {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}
#one {
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
}
#two {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: -30px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 70px solid transparent;
  border-right: 70px solid transparent;
  border-top: 100px solid pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="holder">
  <div id="one">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="two">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

EDIT: prev was not what was asking..

Same for one as always... (basic).. 2 is again a cone but reversed (border-bottom).. #two created the bubble

```css
#holder {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}
#one {
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
}
#two {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 70px solid transparent;
  border-right: 70px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid pink;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="holder">
  <div id="one">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="two">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would think the only problem with this solution is the skippies are solid white. This won't work if the background needs to show through, or this is popping over something.

Comment: you didn't required but that why images are better.. lemme see if a can fix a quick fix.. i think i know already

Comment: @Louis93 it's a basic.. use it to create your own :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a couple of elements for this (I have used three, although I'm sure it's not the most efficient). SVG may also be an option here.

CSS Solution:

```css
.wrap {
  height: 200px;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  background: lightgray;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.a,
.b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  transform: translateX(-200%);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.b {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
.a:before,
.b:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 100% 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px lightgray;
}
.b:before {
  border-radius: 100% 0 0 0;
}
.wrap:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  background: inherit;
  height:50px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius:0 0 50% 50%;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <span class="a"></span>
  <span class="b"></span>
</div>
```